# There has to be an easier way to do regex replaces

Tags: c#, regex, replace

What I'm wanting to do is remove hashtags from a string only where the hashtag symbol directly precedes a string (i.e. #stackoverflow).  Here's what I'm doing:

```
var paragraph = "Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur " + 
    "ridiculus mus. Aliquam bibendum egestas tortor et lobortis. Curabitur malesuada " + 
    "hendrerit volutpat. Aenean commodo finibus faucibus. Sed tincidunt quam eget erat " + 
    "interdum, non ornare est semper. Aliquam ac orci condimentum, pharetra elit eu, #cursus " + 
    "felis. Ut risus mi, tincidunt in #condimentum nec, ornare vel enim. Curabitur nunc est, " + 
    "maximus at ultricies sit #amet, tincidunt eget lectus. Mauris in erat ut lectus varius " + 
    "hendrerit ut id neque. Fusce ultricies efficitur mauris, ac vestibulum purus bibendum sed. " + 
    "Nunc a ultricies eros.";
var expression = @"(?<=\s|^)#(\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*)";
Regex regex = new Regex(expression);
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(paragraph);
foreach(Match m in matches)
{
    paragraph = paragraph.Replace(m.Groups[0].Value, m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Is there a better way to replace the value in the first group of the match with the value in the second group?

Comment: Votes me down and doesn't have the stones to say why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Replace` instead of iterating the `MatchCollection`

```
paragraph = regex.Replace(paragraph, m => m.Groups[1].Value);
```